# Html bootstrap list-group item error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap html page as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Program Management</title>

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="list-group">


            <li class="list-group-item" >
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    hi
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                    helllo
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    fbs
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    angular
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>  
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" >
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    mptt
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    bootstrap
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    angular
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>  
            </li>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When we look at the page in the browser, the list overlaps with the text and is not displayed right. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe at first you shold use

```
<div class="row">
```

with nested columns as follows:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

you are simply missing row class

So your HTML will look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Program Management</title>

        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    hi
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                    helllo
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    fbs
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    angular
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>  
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    mptt
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    bootstrap
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    angular
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                    django
                </div>  
                </div>
            </li>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```